# Communicating with dial-up modems

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, modem, dial-up

I want to if know is there any way to call to a number and send some digits to it after picking up the phone using a dial-up modem in Python?

I already did a Google search and found the [PyModem](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymodem) library, but it is written for Linux and for GSM modems, while I want its counterpart for Windows and for dial-up modems.

I also found some related topics [here](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/026wafpcqh/dialing-out-on-modem) and [here](http://www.icodeguru.com/WebServer/Python-Programming-on-Win32/ch19.htm) that containsome piece of code for working with modems using the `serial` library, but I don't understand why a modem is recognized as a serial device! (Maybe in the past, dial-up modems used COM port to communicate with computers, but my modem is connected to the main board using a PCI slot.)

**So, How can I communicate with a dial-up modem ([d-link 562is](http://www.dlink.ru/mn/products/11/187.html), for example) using python in windows?**

Comment: Regarding COM ports, a lot of device drivers emulate a COM port, even if they're physically connected some other way, because it's a simple interface for the client software to talk to.

Comment: @IMSoP In such that case, shouldn't those appear in the Device Management windows as a COM device?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the description of the d-link 562IS, you'll see mentioned that it is a *software* modem. So most if not all of the functionality is in the driver, not in the hardware.

The Linux driver seems to emulate a serial port because that is the standard way to talk to modems on UNIX. Apparently the windows driver doesn't.

Looking through the `dll` files in the [windows driver](http://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/Modem/DFM-562IS/Drivers/Rev_D/Vista_Win_7/), there is a `ModemOpen` function defined in `MdmXSdk.dll`. You could call that using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).

Or you could try using the [telephony api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950407.aspx).